# how can i fix the backup verification on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: backup, deja-dup, metadata

I'm trying to do the verification on backup using the `Back up now` option but i got the error message:

```
Could not restore ‘~/.cache/deja-dup/metadata’: File not found in backup
```

Any help please?

Comment: It is a good idea to verify the backup, so that you can be sure that it works, if/when you need to restore it. A *full verification* means that you restore it from the backup to a new drive (of the same size or bigger compared to the original drive). - I do not use deja-dup, so we have to wait for someone else to help debug your specific problem.

Comment: in fact the system asks me to verify the backup (weekly) and so it dosen't work :/

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but verification is done automatically by _backup_ not you. That being said, did the last backup complete successfully ?

Comment: I have to enter my password to begin the verification, "did the last backup complete successfully ?"  i don't know ? how can i see?